# Need bash script, that takes first line of a file, and then creates new directories out of words that have been taken

Tags: bash

Need bash script, that takes first line of a file, and then creates new directories out of words that have been taken. The file, that will be checked for first line has to be entered from command line(putty) as well as the directory where u will create those new directories

Can you please guys help me? Im thinking, that at first i have to take the first line of the file(i solved this part). But how do i make new directories with each word that i take from first line? Do I have to make cycle?

Comment: have you tried or googled anything, yet?

Comment: Code writing requests are considered too broad here. Request you to try something, and ask if the script has problems.

Answer (score 1):

`read` reads a line, `mkdir` creates the directories.

```
read dirs < file
mkdir $dirs
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825716/reading-specifed-file-line-and-creating-new-directories-from-words-that-have-bee