# Reading specifed file line and creating new directories from words that have been taking of that file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, debian

```
for file in $*
head -n 1 $file | while read folder
do
mkdir $directory $folder
done
```

Hello guys, I'm having problem with my script. What I want to do is: read first line from my specifed file and create new directories in my specifed directory from words that i have taken from that file.

I'm getting errors like this:

```
./scriptas: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `head'
./scriptas: line 2: `head -n 1 $file | while read folder'
```

And my second question: how do I add a second variable from command line (putty) $directory ?

Example i have file with text:

```
one two three
five seven nine eleven
okey
```

i need script to take the first line and create directories "one" "two" "three"

Comment: Look at my answer, you can use it with one file as well as with a lot of them. The last parameter is the $directory

Answer (score 0):

Updated the script. You can use it in this way:
script.sh "one.txt two.txt three.txt" destdir

```
#! /bin/bash

for files in $1
do
    for i in $(head -n 1 $files)
    do
       if [ -z $2 ]
       then
           mkdir $i
       else
           mkdir $2/$i -p
       fi
    done
done
```

Comment: if [ -z $2 ] what does this line do , mate? Why -z not pwd? thanks by the way :)

Comment: Just input argument checking. You can omit $directory in input arguments so script will create set of directories in your current location

Answer (score 0):

You have to put do before the command in a for/while cycle.

Your code should look like something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$*

for file in $files
do
head -n1 "$file" | while read dname
do
mkdir $dname
done
done
```

as for other variables, the simple syntax is a number behind the $ sign.

so you could do

```
files="$1"
directory="$2"
```

and then run the script as

```
./script.sh "file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt" dir2
```

More complex solutions include getopts and such....

Comment: then you need to do this `mkdir "${direktorija}/${pavadinimas}"`

Comment: It helped, but now it makes only one directory :/ I mean if file contains "one two three" script creates only one folder one two three, what i want to do is create "one" "two" "three" :/